# Check if select control has value when button is clicked in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I would like to know if I can somehow detect if a select control has value when the button is clicked within foreach loop.

This is the markup I have:

```
                                                  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Pack">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="name"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="bg" colspan="3" align="left" height="112px" valign="middle">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div>
                                        <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.TeacherOptions(), optionsValue: 'TeacherId', optionsText: 'TeacherName', optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher'"></select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 n-p m-t-30">
                                            <!-- ko if: !Processing() -->
                                            <a href="javascript:void();" data-bind="click: $root.AddToCart" class="additem-link">Add To Order</a>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

This is add to cart functionality:

```
t.AddToCart = function (n) {
                   if (!t.Busy()) {
                       t.Busy(!0);
                       n.Processing(!0);
                        $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "/webservices/ShopWS.asmx/AddToCart",
                           data: "{'packId': " + n.Id + "}",
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: "json",
                           success: function (i) {
                               if (i.d) {
                                   n.Processing(!13);
                                   t.Busy(!13);
                               }
                           },
                           error: function (n) {
                               u(n);
                           }
                       });
                   }
               };
```

I want to check if the select control has actual value for that item in the foreach loop and if it does then it can add to the cart, otherwise it will not be possible.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's really hard to tell from the way some of the variables are named, but I'm guessing you can check if `n.Id` has a value before making the ajax call. If I'm understanding your question correctly, of course.

Comment: @DonovanM n.Id is coming from another control, its not the actual TeacherId

Comment: Oh wait, you also need a `value` binding. Set it to an observable and that will give you the value of the currently selected item.

Comment: @DonovanM can you give me a sample how can I do that? Thx

Comment: Sure, just added a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the selected item, you can use the `value` binding on a `select` element.

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedItem, options: $root.TeacherOptions(), optionsValue: 'TeacherId', optionsText: 'TeacherName', optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher'"></select>
```

In your view model you would use

```
this.selectedItem = ko.observable(); // You can optionally set it to a specific TeacherId
```

After doing that, `this.selectedItem()`  will return whatever value the currently selected item has.

Comment: Sweet. Happy Holidays to you, too!